# Objective-C consultation: "Receiver type 'void' is not an Objective-C class" error

Tags: objective-c, unity-game-engine

## EDIT:

APP_ID and APP_SIGNATURE are defined as:

```
#define APP_ID @"12345" 
#define APP_SIGNATURE @"123456"
```

I'm new to Objective C and I'm using it to extern some Chartboost code into Unity C#, and I'm here for a little consultation. So please bear with me. Thanks! :D

I have this extern code:

```
extern "C"
{
void applicationDidBecomeActiveExtern()
{
    
    UIApplication*application;
    application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    
    /*Configure chartboost*/
    Chartboost*cb = [Chartboost sharedChartboost];
    cb.appId = APP_ID;
    cb.appSignature = APP_SIGNATURE;
    
    /*Notify the beginning of a user session*/
    [cb startSession];
    
    /*Show an interstitial*/
    [cb showInterstitial];  
}
}
```

But on the line that reads "[cb showInterstitial];", Xcode displays an error "Receiver type 'void' is not an Objective-C class."

I didn't write the function code, I copied it from the guide Chartboost themselves provided. Please comment! Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: Are you missing a header inclusion by any chance?

Comment: I don't think so. It doesn't say any other error aside from this.

Comment: Is this a compile-time or run-time problem?

Comment: It's a compile-time problem, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: What do `APP_ID` and `APP_SIGNATURE` expand to?  Did you happen to examine the preprocessor output (e.g. `gcc -E`)?  It may be that a `#define` has clobbered something into the code that is making the compiler see something slightly different than your original source.

Comment: Hi, @KevinGrant. I edited the question body and added the define code. As for the second part of your question, on whether the preprocessor output something, I'm afraid I didn't understand a thing. Sorry.

Comment: The preprocessor of Objective-C, like C, can replace text before the program is compiled (e.g. if I said `#define cb xyz` somewhere, the compiler would literally see `[xyz showInterstitial];` instead of the original code).  If an error seems confusing it can help to add a compiler option to stop after preprocessing (that's what `gcc -E` does); then you see exactly what the compiler sees after all `#define` values and other preprocessing have been applied.  Alternately, if you *suspect* that `cb` was replaced, you could try renaming this variable everywhere to see if it avoids the error.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I'm taking a stab in the dark here, but maybe `showInterstitial` is a class method, not an instance method.</strike>

Class methods start with a `+`, and instance methods start with a `-`, like this:

```
+(void) showInterstitial; //class method
-(void) showInterstitial; //instance method
```

Stab number two: Are you supposed to have a capital 'B', like `ChartBoost` instead of `Chartboost`?

Comment: And I am going to prove my noobity here. :P How can I verify if it is a class method or instance method? Are the class methods those which are defined in the .h file?

Comment: showInterstitial is defined as follows: "- (void)showInterstitial;" And no, Chartboost is really spelled as "Chartboost", not ChartBoost.

Comment: My final guess would be that the correct Chartboost headers aren't being included, or it has something to do with the `extern "C"`.